# 3 x 350mA on 1 amp circuit

Tags: voltage, power, circuit-analysis

As in the title, could someone please tell me the problems/issues of such a set up, as my landlord says its fine with three X 350mA magnets securing a communal front security door but a contractor said its not fine as the circuit is only one amp.Who's is correct?

Thanks,

Michael.

Comment: 3x0.35 > 1. Whether it would not cause an issue or not is another question.

Comment: We don't know the circuit and how it handles overload conditions and what is the duty cycle of the usage. So they might be both right or wrong. It might work fine until there will be problems. Devices rated for 350mA may have tolerance included on the ratings. It may be a peak current or long term current. Do you have more details?

Comment: The landlord's point of view is that 5% is small.  The contractor's point of view is that 5% is large enough.  When it's said the units are 350 mA, is there an accuracy specified?  The same for the 1 A: what's behind that?  1A breaker? 1A continuous load cable? 1A power supply?.

Comment: I'm sorry I have little experience in this field and no further info, there is obviously more variables than I imagined (i.e. 3x350 >1000 so its not fine) but I now understand its not quite as simple as that. Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that wiring is properly sized here. You need to look at the inrush current when all 3 magnets energize. If it is 3 x 350 = 1050 mA, a time delayed fuse should work fine. If 1050 mA is nominal current, a better rated fuse is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's always safer to ensure that the total current draw of devices on a circuit doesn't exceed its rated capacity. If the magnets are critical for security, this becomes even more important. It would be advisable to either upgrade the circuit or use fewer magnets or magnets with a lower current draw.

Three magnets drawing 350mA each total 1.05A. This exceeds the 1A capacity of the circuit. Overloading can lead to:

1. Circuit failures or trips.
2. Safety risks from overheating.
3. Reduced lifespan of components.
4. Unreliable security function.

The contractor's concerns seem valid. It's better to either reduce the current draw or upgrade the circuit.